# match everything but particular words using regex

Tags: regex

```
var text = "!john david sue !jay";
```

I want to get all strings except words that begin with "!" like "!john" and 
"!jay"...As a result i should get "david" and "sue" strings in this case.

Why doesn't this regex work?

```
/[^(![a-z0-9]+)]/
```

Comment: In JavaScript, you can also do this without a regex: `text.split(" ").filter(function(w) { return w[0] !== "!"; });` will return an array with the words "david" and "sue".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!!)\b\w+
```

See [Regex DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lK8eC7/3)

Your regex does not work because your pattern is inside `[^ ]` (negated character set). All characters are matched literally in a negated char set i.e `(` will match a literal `(` instead of grouping bracket, etc.

Comment: what if i want to select all the characters separately,  after (?<!!)\b\w+ pattern result. In this case d-a-v-i-d s-u-e . Can we do that with only one pattern?

Comment: @tablex I dont think thats possible because we cant differentiate a character in `!john` and `david` with single regex.

Comment: it turns out that javascript doesnt support this pattern(negative lookbehind)..only supports positive, negative lookahead.